# Disable promise transpilation using babel-preset-env?

Tags: javascript, promise, babeljs

I'm using `babel-preset-env` (Babel 6) and I can't find out how to disable the "promise" transpilation.

I tried to use:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "exclude": ["transform-async-to-generator", "es6.promise"]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    [
      "fast-async",
      {
        "spec": true,
        "compiler": { "promises": true, "generators": false }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and, while it doesn't throws any errors (unlike it happens when an invalid option is passed), it still transpiles promises into `runtimeGenerator` functions.

How can I make so that babel-preset-env will transpile everything but preserve promises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, now with the actual .babelrc and mention of `fast-async` and so on... A .babelrc like this seems to be enough to use `fast-async` instead of `regenerator-runtime` etc.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "exclude": ["babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator", "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator"]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "fast-async",
      {
        "spec": true,
        "compiler": { "promises": true, "generators": false }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Promises shouldn't be transpiled to anything using `babel-preset-env`. `async`/`await` is, though.  You can see [here in the Babel playground](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDAFASiQPhmApgdxgAUAnEAWwEsJcUUTcINFsGIUByAC0o7TQDcAKCGhIsAJ5IYAQwgSwwVM2wBvITBhjoMAF7SZ-GZVhx0wgL4CgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2) that

```
const x = () => new Promise((res) => res('hi'));

const y = async () => {
  const z = await x();
};
```

gets transpiled to

```
'use strict';

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { step("next", value); }, function (err) { step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

var x = function x() {
  return new Promise(function (res) {
    return res('hi');
  });
};

var y = function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
    var z;
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            _context.next = 2;
            return x();

          case 2:
            z = _context.sent;

          case 3:
          case 'end':
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee, undefined);
  }));

  return function y() {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}();
```

using the default env settings. If you change the env string to, say, `chrome>60` (or, in fact, interestingly `>4%`!), the code is passed through as-is, as Chrome > 60 supports async/await and arrow functions natively.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused... I'm using the fast-async plugin to transpile async/wait to promises, if I use just that plugin I get promises, if I enable the preset-env I get transformGenerators... but plugins should run before presets, so I'm very confused of why this is happening :-/    Also, this is happening even if I exclude the `transform-async-to-generator`

Comment: Please post your .babelrc or similar in your original question, then.