# Breakpoints do not stay on their line in debugger both in Chrome and VS Code

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

I am stuck trying to figure out why my debuggers do not place the breakpoints on their appropriate lines.

As you can see in the graphics below, the breakpoints do not work as expected:

[Misbehaving breakpoints in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvxSW.gif)

For VS code this is the script I am running:

`"test-script": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon --inspect-brk --exec 'babel-node ./tests/$TEST_SCRIPT'"`

[Disappearing breakpoints in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVPJ1.gif)

I'm not sure if this is a babel/webpack misconfig or something set wrong in the debuggers.

- In `.babelrc` I have tried setting `sourceMaps` to `true`, `"both"`,
  and `"inline"` but that doesn't fix things.
- In my webpack config I
  have `devtool` = `source-map` and `mode` = `development`.

I would really prefer not to put `console.log` statements everywhere and use the debugger as it was intended so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's the same thing, but in other languages, when the breakpoint isn't in it's actual position, means that some code was added or removed after the compilation. Does this ring any bells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like what happens when you're transpiling `async` functions for target environments that don't have them. They end up being so thoroughly transformed so that regeneratorRuntime can handle them that even source maps can't help. I solve it by setting up the project not to transpile `async` functions during dev and debugging on a modern browser that supports them directly. Then we do testing on target pre-`async` browsers with the production (transpiled) build. If we have to track down a problem that only happens when transpiling (very rare), we turn it back on for dev and insert `debugger;` statements. :-|

Comment: Thanks TJ, I thought I was going crazy trying to figure this out. One of the answers to the link provided here questions mentions this **using the default env settings. If you change the env string to, say, chrome>60 (or, in fact, interestingly >4%!), the code is passed through as-is, as Chrome > 60 supports async/await and arrow functions natively.** which fixed it for me in both debuggers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704820/disable-promise-transpilation-using-babel-preset-env

Comment: Is there any way to solve this without disabling the transpiling of async functions during dev? I mean sure that's a good way, but this may cause errors to slip through to prod unnoticed.
Maybe newer versions of babel will do better at the source mapping task ?

Comment: @sktguha - Effective source mapping of `async` function code to the resulting regenerator runtime state machine code appears to be a ***very*** hard problem. I've never seen it done well. But I've also never (literally never) seen a problem where production transpiled code using regenerator runtime had a bug that the equivalent `async` function code run directly did not.

Comment: "But I've also never (literally never) seen a problem where production transpiled code using regenerator runtime had a bug that the equivalent async function code run directly did not."
Oh I see. If no bug happens then yes, for better DX then the answer is good, yes.

Comment: @sktguha - Can't say it's never happened to someone else. :-) Just not to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see. Any scenario where you think this bug might occur ? I am thinking some weird combination of async, await and traditional .then code, with async success or failure callback for .then etc ?

Comment: @sktguha - Fundamentally, it would require that the transpiled code be incorrect. E.g., a bug in the transpiler.

Comment: Yes understood. I was trying to think of more specific case ok how the bug could occur. Could probably get an idea by looking at the GitHub issues on the relevant babel plugin